# How to create multiple polygons on the same google map?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have the following coordinates:

```
 var singida = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-6.926427,33.464355),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-7.057282,33.662109),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-7.122696,33.750000),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-7.209900,33.771973),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-7.471411,33.750000),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-7.536764,33.793945),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-7.536764,33.969727)];


 var Tabora = [
        new google.maps.LatLng(-4.127285,31.684570),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-4.236856,31.684570),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-4.258768,31.508789),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-4.236856,31.486816),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-4.302591,31.464844),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-4.477856,31.420898),
        new google.maps.LatLng(-4.631179,31.464844)];
```

How do I draw the two polygons on the same map? My code below only works for a single polygon

```
 var flightPath = new google.maps.Polygon({
        path: singida,
        geodesic: false,
        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        strokeOpacity: 1.0,
        strokeWeight: 1
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

Just make two separate polygons, one with each of the paths.  This works for me:

```
var singida = [
new google.maps.LatLng(-6.926427, 33.464355),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.057282, 33.662109),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.122696, 33.750000),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.209900, 33.771973),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.471411, 33.750000),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.536764, 33.793945),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.536764, 33.969727)];


var Tabora = [
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.127285, 31.684570),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.236856, 31.684570),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.258768, 31.508789),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.236856, 31.486816),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.302591, 31.464844),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.477856, 31.420898),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.631179, 31.464844)];

var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: singida,
    geodesic: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map
});

var polygon2 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: Tabora,
    geodesic: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map
});
```

(but it looks like the coordinates in the paths are out of order, are missing points or aren't closed correctly)

Another option would be to make an array of polygons.

**code snippet:**

```js
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

var geocoder;
var map;
var polygons = [];

function initialize() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var singida = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-6.926427, 33.464355),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.057282, 33.662109),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.122696, 33.750000),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.209900, 33.771973),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.471411, 33.750000),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.536764, 33.793945),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-7.536764, 33.969727)
  ];


  var Tabora = [
    new google.maps.LatLng(-4.127285, 31.684570),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-4.236856, 31.684570),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-4.258768, 31.508789),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-4.236856, 31.486816),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-4.302591, 31.464844),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-4.477856, 31.420898),
    new google.maps.LatLng(-4.631179, 31.464844)
  ];

  polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: singida,
    geodesic: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map
  }));
  polygons.push(new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: Tabora,
    geodesic: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map
  }));
  for (var j = 0; j < polygons.length; j++) {
    for (var i = 0; i < polygons[j].getPath().getLength(); i++) {
      bounds.extend(polygons[j].getPath().getAt(i));
    }
  }

  map.fitBounds(bounds);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk"></script>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Polygon Hole, setting the position of the second (or another) polygons outside of the first polygon.

Polygon Hole: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/polygon-hole

Ex: Open the link above, and set the coordinates as below:

```
// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's  outer path.
var outerCoords = [
    {lat: 25.774, lng: -80.190},
    {lat: 18.466, lng: -66.118},
    {lat: 32.321, lng: -64.757}
];

// Define the LatLng coordinates for the polygon's inner path.
// Note that the points forming the inner path are wound in the
// opposite direction to those in the outer path, to form the hole.
var innerCoords = [
    {lat: 35.745, lng: -70.579},
    {lat: 38.570, lng: -67.514},
    {lat: 36.570, lng: -64.255},
    {lat: 33.339, lng: -66.668}
];
```

It will make two or more polygons at the same image.

[]'s

Answer (score 1):

Google map provides features of multiple polygon.

```
    var singida = [
new google.maps.LatLng(-6.926427, 33.464355),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.057282, 33.662109),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.122696, 33.750000),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.209900, 33.771973),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.471411, 33.750000),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.536764, 33.793945),
new google.maps.LatLng(-7.536764, 33.969727)];


var Tabora = [
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.127285, 31.684570),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.236856, 31.684570),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.258768, 31.508789),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.236856, 31.486816),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.302591, 31.464844),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.477856, 31.420898),
new google.maps.LatLng(-4.631179, 31.464844)];

var polygon1 = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: [singida, Tabora],
    geodesic: false,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    map: map
});
```

Very simple create multiple array variables and add into paths array